# Can websites uniquely identify users by the sim card used to access the website?

Tags: mobile, websites, user-tracking, simcard

If I was to use a phone's data connection to access a website, and then pop that sim card into another phone to access the same website, could the website tell that I am the same user?

Comment: Probably not, at least not generally. Read about Verizon's Super-Cookie (https://clark.com/technology/how-opt-out-verizons-super-cookie-tracking/) and MobileID (https://www.mobileid.ch/en). Does this concern you?

Comment: Interesting, I am based in Australia and it doesn't look like our Telcos have used Super-Cookies, so I should be safe as far as that goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I am aware of.

- Websites receive the information the web browser provide
- The web browser of the phone devices is an app that has not the
  permission to get the SIM data of the mobile device (unless it was an
  malicious app)
- Information of the device apart from cookies does include the User
  Agent, but that string of information that not include that kind of
  information.
- You can not relay on IP addresses, your phone provider may use
  DHCP/nat and the phone could use a different phone provider network
  (roaming)

I would suggest using client side certificates, when the phone is changed remove the certificate and when user is no longer trusted revoke it.